# compare n columns in datafarme with dictionary and update the k column values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have Dataframe around 1M rows

```
ID      SEGMENT group   CODE_1      CODE_2      CODE_3      CODE_4      CODE_5      CODE_6      CODE_7      CODE_8      CODE_9  CODE_10     
100006  History ML1     Offer_25    Offer_4     Offer_8     Offer_10    Offer_2     Offer_9     Offer_3     Offer_1     Offer_7 Offer_12
100007  History ML1     Offer_35    Offer_4     Offer_18    Offer_10    Offer_22    Offer_9     Offer_3     Offer_1     Offer_7 Offer_12
1000065 History ML1     Offer_5     Offer_40    Offer_8     Offer_1     Offer_21    Offer_9     Offer_3     Offer_1     Offer_7 Offer_13
10001   History ML1     Offer_5     Offer_41    Offer_18    Offer_15    Offer_2     Offer_19    Offer_3     Offer_11    Offer_7 Offer_12
900010  History ML1     Offer_15    Offer_4     Offer_18    Offer_10    Offer_20    Offer_19    Offer_3     Offer_6     Offer_7 Offer_12
```

And also Dictionary having same offers in Categories

```
{'Cat1': ['Offer_1', 'Offer_2',  'Offer_3', 'Offer_4', 'Offer_5','Offer_7','Offer_8','Offer_9','Offer_10'],
 'Cat2': ['Offer_6'],
 'Cat3': ['Offer_11','Offer_13','Offer_14','Offer_31'],
 'Cat4': ['Offer_12'],
 'Cat5': ['Offer_15','Offer_16','Offer_18','Offer_19','Offer_20','Offer_21','Offer_22','Offer_23','Offer_24','Offer_25','Offer_26','Offer_27','Offer_28','Offer_29','Offer_30','Offer_33'],
 'Cat6': ['Offer_17'],
 'Cat7': ['Offer_32'],
 'Cat8': ['Offer_34', 'Offer_39', 'Offer_40'],
 'Cat9': ['Offer_35'],
 'Cat10': ['Offer_36'],
 'Cat11': ['Offer_37'],
 'Cat12': ['Offer_38'],
 'Cat13': ['Offer_41']}
```

Need to extract 6 offers from columns code_1 to code_10 where each value is compared with dict and needs to make sure at most 2 offers are selected for each category. In case 10 offers in pool cant fulfil at most constraint then leave the left over offers as it is.

The approach i am following is that i am getting each datafarme row in a list and then comparing it with dict. Please let me know if there is a better approach.

Added approach below, it works fine and is fast as well but too complex and lot of looping:

```
num_offers = 6

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    final_lst= []
    intrim_lst = {}
    list_append = []
    new_dict ={}
    for i in range (1,11):
        offer_code = "CODE_"+str(i)
        list_append.append(row[offer_code])
    for i,val in enumerate(list_append):
        for key, value in d.items():
            if val in value:
                if i > 0 :
                    j = 1
                    for key1, value1 in new_dict.items():                    
                        if key in value1:
                            j = j +1
                    new_dict.update({val :[key,j]})
                else:
                    new_dict.update({val :[key,1]})
#     print(new_dict)
    #Logic to get at most two offers from each category
    for i,val in enumerate(list_append):
        for key, value in new_dict.items():
            if val in key:
                if val == key:
                    if int(new_dict[key][1]) <=2:
                        final_lst.append(key)                    
        del new_dict[val]
#     print("final_lst",final_lst)
    intrim_lst = [item for item in list_append if item not in final_lst]
    len_offers = num_offers - len(final_lst)
    if len_offers > 0:
        get_intrim_offers = intrim_lst[:len_offers]
        final_lst = final_lst + get_intrim_offers
    print("final_offer_lst",final_lst)
```

Comment: Please share your current approach, which should include the data in a convenient format.

Comment: Added Approach still trying figure out the logic to get at most 2 offers from category